# Difference between | and ||

Tags: command-line, bash

What is the difference between | and || ?

When I run this command :

```
ls -la | id
```

I get the result of `id`

When I run this command
:

```
ls -la || id
```

I get the result of `ls -la`

So what is the difference between them ?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

`|` is the pipe operator, which passes the output of the first command to the one that follows.

from `man bash`:

> A  pipeline  is  a  sequence  of one or more commands separated by the character |.  The format for a pipeline is:
>
> ```
> [time [-p]] [ ! ] command [ | command2 ... ]
> ```
>
> The standard output of command is connected via a pipe to the standard input of command2.

In the example you provide, `id` doesn't seem to do anything with the output of `ls` so it just returns the same output as running `id` alone.

---

`||` is the logical OR operator, and specifies what to do if the first command returns `false` or fails (is non-zero).

from `man bash`:

> The  control  operators  &&  and || denote AND lists and OR lists, respectively.  An AND list has the form
>
> ```
> command1 && command2
> ```
>
> command2 is executed if, and only if, command1 returns an exit status of zero.
>
> An OR list has the form
>
> ```
> command1 || command2
> ```
>
> command2 is executed if and only if command1 returns a non-zero exit status.  The  return  status  of AND and OR lists is the exit status of the last command executed in the list.

In your example, `ls -la` runs successfully so the `id` command isn't run. If you did the following:

```
ls -z || id
```

and try to pass an invalid option `z` to `ls`, then it fails and the `id` command gets run.

Comment: You may want to mention that technical term for the || symbol is logical OR . Would probably be beneficial to include quote from bash man page

Comment: It also in more technical terms, OR runs right command when exit status of left command is non-zero

Comment: @Serg I thought the same so I added my own answer mostly quoting sources OP should have found in the first place before asking imo

Comment: @cat you should have felt free to edit my answer :)

Comment: Maybe use the expression "short circuiting" for logical or as well.

Answer (score 6):

`|` is the pipe operator. From [this `man sh`](http://heirloom.sourceforge.net/sh/sh.1.html):

> A pipeline is a sequence of one or more commands separated by |. The standard output of each command but the last is connected by a pipe(2) to the standard input of the next command. Each command is run as a separate process; the shell waits for the last command to terminate. The value of a pipeline is the exit status of its last command.

```
A | B | C
```

Will take the standard output of A (what it prints to the screen) and give it to B as standard input, like what you would type in an interactive mode, and B gives its stdout to C.

```
history | grep word
```

`history` prints all of your shell's history, and `grep` prints lines matching a pattern, so this finds every entry in your shell history where you've used `word`, because `grep` reads STDIN when not given a filename as an argument.

```
history | tail -n10 | head -n5
```

Gets the first 5 lines of the last 10 lines of `history`, because `tail` and `head` both read STDIN when no filename is given.

---

On the other hand, `||` is the logical OR operator, exactly equivalent to the same operator in C and C-like languages. Again, from that `man sh`:

> The symbols && and ||, respectively, cause the list following to be executed only if the preceding pipeline returns a zero or non zero value, respectively. Newlines may appear in a list, instead of semicolons, to delimit commands.

```
stat filename || echo "no such file or directory" 
stat filename && echo "file exists"
```

If `stat` doesn't find the filename, it returns a nonzero exit status, and if it does, it exits successfully with 0. This is the inverse of C. (Highly contrived examples as `stat` gives such information anyways.)

These are essentially the same as, but shorter than, checking the last command's exit status explicitly:

```
stat filename
if [ $? -gt 0 ]; then
  echo "no such file or directory"
fi
```

etc.

Comment: @Serg :) I was working on it